# how to return array as value of column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

we are NGO organiztaion and we have donors who give donation every month so i want to display a table show the name of the donor and all months and under every month put true if he give the donation of this month and false if not.

something like that

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Donor | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   A   |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
|   B   |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
|   C   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  1  |
|   D   |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now i make 2 tables in mysql database :
1)- Donors
2)- Donation_Months

Donors :

```
+-----+------+
| id  | name |
+-----+------+
|  1  |  A   |
|  2  |  B   |
|  3  |  C   |
|  4  |  D   |
+-----+----- +
```

Donation_Months :

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| dm_id | do_id | month |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |  Jan  |
|   2   |   2   |  Feb  |
|   3   |   2   |  Mar  |
|   4   |   2   |  Apr  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

this table shows that 2nd donor(B) give us his donations in those 4 months

Now i want to make a sql statement relate **Donors table** with **Donation_Months table** and display the result like in the top table figure.

The point here i want to get many rows for every donor but i want to display them in one loop or one row

How can i do that ??
I tried with many methods but with no point like that

```
SELECT accounts.*, (SELECT * FROM donation_months where donation_months.domo_account_id = accounts.account_id) AS months FROM `accounts`
```

accounts = donors

the idea i want to do, i want to get a result array of second table based on donor id and store it as text in temp column like that

```
+-------+------------------------+
| Donor |      temp_months       |
+-------+------------------------+
|   A   |         ()             |
|   B   |  (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)  |
|   C   |         ()             |
|   D   |         ()             |
+-------+------------------------+
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i make an edit and add some idea i want to do .. can you help me how to return array as value of themp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to us *conditional aggregation* :

```
SELECT
    d.name,
    COALESCE(MAX(m.month = 'Jan'), 0) Jan,
    COALESCE(MAX(m.month = 'Fev'), 0) Fev,
    COALESCE(MAX(m.month = 'Mar'), 0) Mar,
    COALESCE(MAX(m.month = 'Apr'), 0) Apr,
    COALESCE(MAX(m.month = 'May'), 0) May
FROM
    donors d
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT month FROM Donation_Months) x
    LEFT JOIN Donation_Months m ON m.do_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.name;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exM4cAzaPyMyGoQij4jpCA/1)**

---

According to your edited post, you might want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to display all months in a single column, like :

```
SELECT
    d.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.month ORDER BY m.dm_id) temp_months
FROM
    donors d
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT month FROM Donation_Months) x
    LEFT JOIN Donation_Months m ON m.do_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.name;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exM4cAzaPyMyGoQij4jpCA/2)**

Comment: i make an edit and add some idea i want to do .. can you help me how to return array as value of themp field?

Comment: Wow! you the man .. both worked perfectly :)
But what is the best method to use? the first one or second and check if this month in this array or not ??

Comment: The disadvantage of the first is that you need to explicitly name each column/month in the SELECT.  The disadvantage in the second is that you need to do some conditional php work to output.  I'd go with the first if you are happy to display 12 months in the output table, then just name each month in the SELECT.

Comment: @GMB Could you help me in this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673501/1731660

Answer (score -1):

Cool! GroupConcat method working fine I am getting date result by array
check this out [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAaRP.png)

Comment: please specify the query example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32785366)