# how to store result array of joined table in the row result in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have 3 tables :

1. donations
2. purposes
3. expenses

Donations :

```
+--------+------+
| do_id  | name |
+--------+------+
|  1     |  A   |
|  2     |  B   |
|  3     |  A   |
|  4     |  D   |
|  5     |  B   |
|  6     |  B   |
|  7     |  A   |
|  8     |  B   |
+--------+----- +
```

purposes:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| pu_id | do_id | purpose|
+-------+-------+--------+
|   1   |   2   |  abc   |
|   2   |   2   |  def   |
|   3   |   2   |  gih   |
|   4   |   3   |  jkl   |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

expense :

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| ex_id | do_id | expense |
+-------+-------+---------+
|   1   |   2   |   abc   |
|   2   |   2   |   def   |
|   3   |   2   |   gih   |
|   4   |   3   |   jkl   |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

Now i want to make query to get all donations for donor **B** and join **purposes table** to get all purposes related to every **donation_id** then join **expenses table** to get all expenses related to **donation_id** and put all of that in every loop independently something like that

```
Row number 0

donation_id = 1
array(purposes)
array(expenses)

Row number 1

donation_id = 2
array(purposes)
array(expenses)

Row number 2

donation_id = 3
array(purposes)
array(expenses)

Row number 3

donation_id = 4
array(purposes)
array(expenses)
```

This is my try :

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `donation_purposes` 
    WHERE `donation_purposes`.`dopu_donation_id` = 4
) AS `purposes` 
FROM `donations` 
WHERE `donation_id` = '4'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like you are rather vague about how you are going to use the result. Are you just going to view them as a text or do you want some kind of JSON structure in the end? You could use "group by" and "group_concat" to get some texts with your data, but I can't really see a useful use fore it in the context you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solive this with an aggregate query using [MySQL aggregate function `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg), like :

```
SELECT
    d.do_id,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(p.purpose) purposes,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(e.expense) expenses
FROM donations d
INNER JOIN purposes p ON p.do_id = d.do_id 
INNER JOIN expense e  ON e.do_id = d.do_id 
GROUP BY d.do_id
```

I you want to avoid duplicate values in the array, and as `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` (sadly) does not support the `DISTINCT` option, you can move aggregation to subqueries, like :

```
SELECT
    d.do_id,
    p.agg purpose,
    e.agg expenses
FROM donations d
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT do_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(purpose) agg FROM purposes GROUP BY do_id
) p ON p.do_id = d.do_id 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT do_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(expense) agg FROM expense GROUP BY do_id
) e  ON e.do_id = d.do_id
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aG8j8Ume154WF2WWX3QeAn/1)** returns :

```
| do_id | purpose               | expenses              |
| ----- | --------------------- | --------------------- |
| 2     | ["abc", "def", "gih"] | ["abc", "def", "gih"] |
| 3     | ["jkl"]               | ["jkl"]               |
```

Comment: is there any other way because i have this error FUNCTION shoryan.JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist

Comment: @eng.ahmed the docs says "Added in MySQL 5.7.22." so you probably have a slightly older MySQL version. Try to put something like this in the DB fiddle above: CONCAT('["',Group_concat(e.expense separator '","'),'"]') expenses

Answer (score 0):

- 1st Select Query Purposes

  ```
  SELECT purposes.* FROM purposes
  LEFT JOIN donations
  ON purposes.do_id = donations.do_id
  WHERE donations.do_id = '2' //This depends on the id of the donation
  ORDER BY purposes.do_id ASC
  ```
- 2nd Select Query Expenses

  ```
  SELECT expense.* FROM expense
  LEFT JOIN donations
  ON expense.do_id = donations.do_id
  WHERE donations.do_id = '2' //This depends on the id of the donation
  ORDER BY expense.ex_id ASC
  ```

All queries generated are from the table structure you've provided, but your question is quite vague!!